# How to read the input from a messagebox?

Tags: vb.net

Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Give an ID to mutate", "Mutation", "Enter your ID");

I'm able to read the input, but how?

Also, is there a possiblity that if I press a number like 1 and I´ll get all the information below?

`Mp3Player player1 = new Mp3Player(1, "GET Technologies .inc", "HF 410", 4096, 129.95M, 500);`

Comment: What Do You Want To Do Man?!!

Comment: what do you mean get the info below? Like, a popup opens and displays the text `Mp3Player player1 = new Mp3Player(1, "GET Technologies .inc", "HF 410", 4096, 129.95M, 500);`?

Comment: Like, I got an array.. If I press number 2, can I get all the information of that specific ID. I'm actually wanting to make changes to that Mp3 player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the result:

```
string id = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Give an ID to mutate", "Mutation", "Enter your ID");
```

If you're trying to convert this to a number, you'll need to convert the string to a number:

```
string idString = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Give an ID to mutate", "Mutation", "Enter your ID");

int id;
if (int.TryParse(idString, out id))
{
    Mp3Player player = new Mp3Player(id, "GET Technologies .inc", "HF 410", 4096, 129.95M, 500);
}
else
{
     // The user typed something that wasn't a number
}
```